# Instagram live video streaming API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, live-streaming

I'm looking for the solution to upload live video streaming via Instagram SDK.

I have read the doc [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer), but It seems very basic APIs they are providing.

Is it possible to start live video streaming on Instagram via SDK/APIs?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you found any help yet from instagram?

Comment: @ManabKumarMal not yet

Comment: Is there any other way you found to make it working? Or you have any support mail to mail Instagram to get it working?

Comment: @NishchitDhanani any news on this?

Comment: Nope... I am not watching it. If you'll get any solution, then please share it here.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: no IG API, origin policy is the IG app itself.

I know for the moment I they don't plan on offering that functionality, though I expect chat API to come through by the end of the year or in 2019, unless there's a major overhaul of the Live section of the app.

IG Live is an experience made for the typical Instagram use case (mobile phone with the app installed, a camera and internet connection).

Considering the recent release of IG TV, there's definitely a chance they're looking at extending APIs as tech companies generally support programmatic content gymnastics.

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: @BrunoMartinsPro AFAIK no plans to ever allow any sort of streaming except from the IG app. There exist some hacks to get it to work with OBS though, which you can find online.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your software/service with 3d party service called RTMP.IN
Here is the [API documentation](https://rtmp.stoplight.io/). You can create/start/stop broadcast, get stats/heartbeat, comments etc.

Comment: The link is dead. I think it might be using some workaround to do it because IG still doesn't allow creating live streaming.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/live_media/